# Linux Mint 18.3 Freezing while away from computer

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

On Linux 18.3

When away from my computer (never happens while I'm actively using it), Mint will freeze. The symptoms are:

- Mouse is able to move, but does not 'unlock' screen from screensaver
- Screensaver is frozen displaying time when it was last active
- 'blind typing' the password does not work
- Processes are not functioning -- mainly, I can tell by the Plex server I am also hosting on the machine not being reachable by other devices while the machine is frozen

Previously I was having to hard reboot (hold power button to kill machine, restart), until coming across the command CTRL + ALT + Backspace, which DOES save me from having to hard restart, but all my open apps, windows, etc. are still closed and I have to reopen everything.

Answer (score 0):

If ctrl+alt+bkspc works, then *LINUX* is not frozen, but only your X session.  since it seems to happen when the screensaver activates, I'd start troubleshooting down that path.  Search for bugs with Mint in that regard, check your X server logs, etc...